# Show running processes with file name(s)?

Tags: linux, process, open-files

I am using putty to connect my linux server which my sites are in. I can run

```
# ps aux | less
```

to show running processes. But I want to display which files running these processes ?

I have also tried

```
# ps aux | grep <pid>
```

But getting this error:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
```

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: in `grep <pid>`, you're supposed to replace `<pid>` with your actual process id (it's a number).  `<pid>` is just a placeholder, not something you should actually type.

Answer (score 15):

`ps aux | grep <pid>` isn't a shell command. The notation `<pid>` is a common convention to mean “put the PID there”. For example, if the PID is 1234, you'd run `ps aux | grep 1234`. This isn't a very useful command, you might as well run `ps u 1234`.

Your question isn't very clear. What do you mean by “with file names”? If you want to see what executable the process 1234 is running:

```
ls -l /proc/1234/exe
```

If you want to see what files that process has open:

```
ls -l /proc/1234/fd
```

If you want to see the full command line with arguments:

```
tr '\0' '\n' </proc/1234/cmdline
```

If you prefer to use commands, `lsof -p1234` shows all the files the process has open. `ps uww 1234` shows various pieces of information about process 1234 including the full command line.

Answer (score 6):

try executing the following:

```
ps -ef
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `ps aux | grep <PID>` is useful when you want to show the details for a specific process whose [`PID`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier) (Process Identifier) is represented by `<PID>`.

For example (`ps aux | grep 'firefox\|USER'` means print only lines that contein `firefox`or `USER`):

```
ps aux | grep 'firefox\|USER'
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
terdon  9021  2.5 11.8 1950888 970832 ?      Sl   Apr03 108:41 /opt/firefox/firefox
```

So, the PID for my `firefox`instance is 9021. So, to use the command you are trying to run, I would replace `<PID>` with `9021`:

```
ps aux | grep 9021
terdon  9021  2.5 11.5 1948776 942640 ?      Sl   Apr03 109:03 /opt/firefox/firefox
```

---

Now, I am not sure what you mean by "display which files running these processes". If you mean display which files these processes are using, `ps aux` is one way of doing so. Say I have opened the file `/usr/share/doc/nano/faq.html` using this command:

```
 firefox /usr/share/doc/nano/faq.html
```

I could see which file `firefox` had opened using `ps` :

```
ps aux | grep firefox
terdon   31763 18.7  1.0 682916 84352 pts/10   Sl+  17:10   0:02 firefox /usr/share/doc/nano/faq.html
```

The opened file is shown as one of the arguments passed to firefox. Note that the PID is different (it is now `31763` instead of `9021`) that is because every running program has its own unique PID.

---

Another useful command is `top`. If you run it with the `-c` switch it will show the arguments passed to a command, and with `-u <your user>` it will only show processes started by your user name (replace `<your user>` with your actual user name):

```
top -c -u terdon
```

This is the output on my local machine (user `terdon` is only running two processes):

```
top - 17:14:41 up 3 days, 49 min, 14 users,  load average: 0.48, 0.54, 0.55
Tasks: 228 total,   1 running, 226 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
%Cpu(s):  7.1 us,  5.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 86.5 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.9 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   8187940 total,  8007220 used,   180720 free,   349264 buffers
KiB Swap:  8191996 total,     5556 used,  8186440 free,  4173004 cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                       
31573 terdon    20   0 24900 5576 1684 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.20 bash                                                          
31763 terdon    20   0  666m  77m  28m S   0.0  1.0   0:02.39 firefox /usr/share/doc/nano/faq.html
```

For an explanation of the information shown by `top`, see [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/575330/151431) to a related question on SU.

Answer (score 0):

some characters under shell are for special purpose  like < > ? " ; ...

grep PID is not useful because PID is process id and grep will find similar numeric ...